# Is Common Lisp king in the ease of use department according to this graph?

Tags: programming-languages, common-lisp, usability

So I found this [fascinating plot](http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/lang.rank_.plot_.q1151.png) of programming languages cross-ranked by SO tags versus Github project use:

[image: Programming languages]

So, just naively interpreting this graph I figured that the more SO posts you have, the more difficulties you are having (bugs, unexpected behavior, trying to figure out how to do something, etc), whereas the Github is a popularity metric. Therefore, according to this line of thinking, stuff in the lower right corner would be "relatively easy to use", whereas stuff in the upper left would be the opposite. Stuff on the line would be "normal ease of use", I am guessing.

If this interpretation is correct, that would suggest **Common Lisp** is king when it comes to ease of use, strangely enough. On the other hand, Cuda, SQL and XML, would be the kings of compexity and "unreproduceable results" (no surprises there, LOL).

Now, one interesting thing is that VimL is so far on the "easy" side, even though it is reputedly a "quirky" language. Maybe that disproves the theory... or maybe VimL is really easy to use and emacs people are just vocal about "how hard it is to use", even though it is not, hmmm....

Is this interpretation accurate?

**UPDATE**

It looks like Common Lisp was just an abberation due to bad data collection on the part of the originator. A new plot has been generated which is presumably more accurate and looks like this:

[image: Programming Language Rankings #2]

So here Lisp has a more normal profile, and it seems TeX and VimL are the actual "easy to use/reliable" languages. SQL/XML and Cuda remain the baddies. Of course, if you went to Cuda looking for an easy-to-use, predictable language environment, you obviously went to the wrong place.

Comment: No, the graph is simply wrong. That's because their software is buggy and fails to find Common LIsp Q&As on Stackoverflow.  It's just a bug on their side. For some reason they are not able to fix it or even to detect that they have a bug. Shows how much their graph is worth...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Okay, that is why I was asking, trying to determine what we can infer from the graph or if some of its data is suspect.

Comment: Most of the code on Github are *libraries*. On the other hand, most of uses of SQL are in *applications*. So, as a language popularity metric, I think that Github is very flawed.

Comment: The graph has been corrected, see http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2015/01/14/language-rankings-1-15/

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks for the update, I will modify the question.

Comment: @TylerDurden The graph rests on flawed assumptions and should be ignored. TeX is offtopic on SO, and there exists an entire _[site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)_ dedicated to it on SE, as does [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). Vim, Emacs and Shell will duke it out mostly on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). And a high # of posts on SO about a language may be due to its extreme popularity, not its difficulty.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist You are missing the point, which is the RATIO between SO posts and Github popularity. The ratio is the metric.

Comment: @TylerDurden But I'm in part arguing that people may prefer fora other than SO for discussing languages that are used in Github projects, skewing the results. To pile on more examples, [r] is the most popular tag in [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) bar none, and I've seen many of the languages below the line being used in [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). I also argue that if a small number of experts develop a lot of code in a difficult language, then it will rank low on SO and high on Github (below the curve) – appearing _"usable"_ precisely when it is not.